# Is the url been rewritten? tuckey - urlrewrite

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I use http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ library

I am trying to detect if the URL of the page has been rewritten or not,

I come up with something like this:

```
if(req.getRequestURL().toString().contains("?")) {
  //do stuff
}
```

But the url of the page that is rewritten is the same as the normal one:

```
request.getRequestURL().append("?").append(request.getQueryString()).toString();
```

So my question is: how to detect if the URL has been rewritten or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Tuckey doesn't provide any direct way of testing wheter it actually rewrote a URL or not.

I think your best bet is to add an additional request parameter on the  rewrite rule and then test for that parameter.

Something like:

```
<to type="redirect">/some/url?rewritten</to>
```

and then something like

```
boolean rewritten = request.getParameter("rewritten") != null;
```